# "-- more --" is disabled when I use :g/pattern

Tags: vim

I used to analyze logs with vim and I always use the command :g/*pattern* to filter what I want. But in some OS versions this command doesn't work like the "more" or "less" commands. All output is shown in a straight way. I'd like to set vim editor to stop the output and show one page at a time. Is there a setting option for that?

Comment: have you tried to make the two vimrc confs same? I cannot produce your problem here.

Comment: They only have one line: syntax off . I'm trying to find out the property to turn on/off this feature but I couldn't do that.

Comment: Try [`:set more`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/message.html#more-prompt)